# How to trim a disk image?

Tags: backup, dd, disk-image

I have a copy of my RPi's SD card made with `dd if=/dev/mmblk0 of=backup.img`. This creates a 32GB file. Only about 6GB of it is actually used, the rest is just data from deleted files. How would I remove the old, useless data? It doesn't have to shrink the image file, just zero out whatever isn't needed

Comment: Especially the fragment: "To efficiently clear empty space within a partition, run `fstrim` on the loop-mounted filesystem, just like you would on an SSD. (This will actually make the image file sparse.)"

Comment: After I make a dd image of my Raspbian SD card, I first resize it using resize2fs, as explained in Kamil's link. I have 9 GB used, and resize2fs gets a 32 GB raw image down to around 9.5 GB, and then I move the image to a Windows share and use any Zip tool to make a compressed archive (usable by Balena Etcher) of around 6 GB. If I flash the image to a new card I would expand the filesystem on first boot.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I think that's exactly it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have been successfully using a script called pishrink by Drew Bonasera ('Drewsif') to back up a headless Raspberry Pi 4 (it works for all models). It is useful because after using dd to make the image it optionally shrinks the image with resize2fs to a little above the data size, and also can optionally insert a run-once command into the image to make Raspbian expand the file system when the image is flashed to a card and used for the first time to boot a Pi. I have been making 8 GB images from a 32 GB card.

This means you could flash a smaller card than the original, provided the shrunk image size is smaller than the new card.

https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink

It is nice to compress the image to a zip archive (Balena Etcher can use these) but... it is painfully slow if you let the Pi hardware do the compression. As the finished image ends up in a Windows shared folder mounted on the Pi, after PiShrink has finished my script uses sshpass on the Pi to command Windows (OpenSSH enabled) to run [pigz](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/pigz-for-windows.html) (a fast command line parallel Zip tool)  and can get the zip archive down to around 5.5 to 6 GB. Or you could use other methods (WinRar, Winzip, 7-zip etc).